# Why isn't my browser setting the httpCookie cookie automatically upon request?

Tags: .net, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have ASP.NET Web API that utilizes .NET 6 and I'm trying to send a cookie in a response. To be more specific I'm trying to send a response that contains a [httpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) cookie.

The request comes from http://localhost:8080/login and it's sent to the server at https://localhost:7212/auth/login which sends the response back to http://localhost:8080/login.

As far as I know this can't and shouldn't be set by the client manually.

The idea here is that the client requests a response from the server, the server replies with a response and the client sets the cookie automatically.

What I have on the server is this

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append( "Token", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true
    });
    return Ok();
}
```

And the client requests a response from that endpoint like so

```
function getToken() {
axios.post('https://localhost:7212/auth/login')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

And when using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) to inspect the request, it manages to catch the cookie.

[image]
[image]

BUT! When looking at the cookies section in my browser, either Chrome or Firefox, there is no cookie set.
[image]

I do get a successful `200` response back from the server in the browser.
[image]

I personally was told that you can't automagically set a cookie with a response, but that seems to be a false statement. Because looking at [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/ULFAgn2ITko?t=1303) we can clearly see that when he makes a request to the endpoint and switches back to the browser, without setting the token manually with the help of JavaScript, the token has been set.

This is how CORS has been configured in `Program.cs`

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");

                      });
});

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

What's actually going on here and what am I doing wrong that causes the cookie to not be set like it is in the [video](https://youtu.be/ULFAgn2ITko?t=1303).

Comment: Is the axios call in your browser cross-origin? That is, does it go to a different combination of `https://host:port` than the page which sends it? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Updated the question showing where the request is coming from and where the response if being sent as well as showing how I've configured CORS. However, I'm not getting any CORS errors in the console in the browser.

Comment: [WithCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) should be set to true before making the request,  try to add { withCredentials: true }. And check if cookies are disabled in your browser

Comment: I tried adding that to the request, still no go, and cookies are not disabled, no.

Comment: Beside { withCredentials: true }in your request,  try to add ('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' in your Cors too. If not wok, read  [SameSite cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)